# When (if ever) will testmethod fail to compile?

Tags: apex, unit-test, bestpractice, compile-error, deprecation

I just recently learned from the `Apex Developer Guide` documentation on the **[IsTest Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm)**:

> The testMethod keyword is now deprecated. Use the @isTest annotation on classes and methods instead.

Are there API Versions where use of this keyword will cause a compile fail? If not, do we know if/when that is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The testMethod keyword is now deprecated. Use the @isTest annotation on classes and methods instead.

I've been telling people not to use this for ages; @isTest is not just a testMethod replacement, it allows us to specify things like parallel testing boundaries and database isolation.

> Are there API Versions where use of this keyword will cause a compile fail?

Not at this time. There's no specific announcement at this time, so it's probably at least a year out (v45.0 or later). Besides, if they tie it to a version, then it'll be like database isolation and unit test method isolation (v27.0/v28.0). Older classes will work for some time (probably at least 3-5 years), but newer classes will compile-fail if you specify a newer version. Note that the actual dates are just examples, since we don't have a formal time line.

> If not, do we know if/when that is coming?

It may never come. The bulk keyword, introduced in the earliest days of Apex Code, is still supported, despite being vestigial for about a decade now. Most likely, given they've marked it as deprecated, it'll be version-locked at some point, but I doubt it will ever fully go away, as long as people are using it, which may well take a decade or longer.

Comment: Does that mean you can do `IsTest(isParallel=true)` at the method level? So

`@IsTest(isParallel=true) static testA(){}` ?

Comment: @EricSSH I hadn't actually tried, but no, you can't specify parallel at the method level. I wonder if this is something they'll support later?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anywhere in documentation and Google search that the deprecation will cause/have caused problems.

Personally I don't think Salesforce will cause a compile fail specifically for this keyword, as this would be existing in code in all instances and it would've been a nightmare for companies to clean up and change. Release documentation would've been pretty clear of any deadline.

I also created a few test classes in recently unwittingly still including testMethod (API ver 41), and was able to deploy them in production.

Best I think would be to create a Salesforce case and ask them.

Comment: I don't think they would cause compile failures *before a specific version*. Also the new release is 42.0 so I would be surprised to see it happen in any version below that.